# Оптимизация алгоритма поиска простых чисел на Python3

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, числа, простые-числа

Как можно увеличить скорость поиска простых чисел в диапазоне от M до N методом "Решета Эратосфета" для больших чисел/диапазонов?

```
import math

def getPrimes(M, N):
  N += 1
  sieve = set(range(2, N))
  for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(N))):
    if i in sieve:
      sieve -= set(range(2*i, N, i))

  return sorted(i for i in sieve if i >= M) # Особенно смущает эта строка
```

Тестирую производительность:

```
from timeit import timeit

print('Время выполнения:', timeit(lambda: getPrimes(1000000, 5000000), number=1), 'сек')

# Время выполнения: 5.557504795000568 сек
```

Comment: Очень рекомендую ознакомиться- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n/2068548#2068548

Comment: Промежуток `getPrimes(1, 10)`  -> `[2, 3, 5, 7, 9]`. Девятка - не простое число.

Answer (score 1):

Удалось слегка оптимизировать исходный алгоритм:

```
import math
from timeit import timeit


def getPrimes_optimized(M, N):

    N += 1
    sieve = set(range(3, N, 2))  # пропускаем четные, т.к. кроме 2 - простых четных чисел не бывает
    sieve.add(2)  # добавляем двойку по вышеуказанной причине

    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(N)), 2):  # тоже самое, поэтому начинаем итерировать с тройки с шагом 2
        if i in sieve:
            sieve -= set(range(2*i, N, i))

    return sorted(i for i in sieve if M <= i)


print(getPrimes_optimized(1000000, 5000000) == getPrimes(1000000, 5000000))

print('Время выполнения:', timeit(lambda: getPrimes_optimized(1000000, 5000000), number=10), 'сек')
print('Время выполнения:', timeit(lambda: getPrimes(1000000, 5000000), number=10), 'сек')
```

На моем компе показывает следующий результат:

```
True  #  полученные списки идентичны
Время выполнения: 23.673116489000677 сек  # мой оптимизированный вариант с number=10
Время выполнения: 33.008412028997554 сек  # оригинальный вариант с number=10
```